# Many iexplorer instances open when clicking on a mailto link

Tags: windows-7, firefox, internet-explorer, windows-live-mail

Whenever I click on a *mailto* link, my computer gets whacko and starts a recurrent series of calls that open more and more instances of *iexplorer*. I need to manually enter the task manager and kill the process tree. Then the new *iexplorer* instances stop appearing.

I'm using FireFox to browse and Windows Live Mail for e-mail on Windows 7. I have Outlook 2013 installed but don't use it (haven't even configured it).

Don't know when the misbehavior started or what I could've done right before. Installed all updates. Reinstalled the obvious things.

How do I stop it?
What can be causing it?

[image]

Comment: Please go to the Control Panel `Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations` and check your association for the `MAILTO` protocol. What is it set to?

Comment: Please see my addition above. It's weird - I don't have the *MAILTO* in the list at all. Or do I and I just don't realize it?

Comment: Can you open regedit and tell us what `HKCR\mailto\shell\open\command` is set to?

Comment: Nothing, actually. I don't have that key in the registry at all. I'm assuming that *HKCR* means *HKEY_Classes_Root*. In fact, I made a search for *mailto* and there's only one reference, in *PROTOCOL\_Handler_\mailto* with *CLSID* set to a guid. What does it tell us?

Answer (score 12):

I've had the same problem and managed to solve it, so hopefully this helps someone.

I tracked down the problem and apparently a registry entry for handling of mailto: protocol has been removed. Probable culprit is IE10 installer, but I'm not sure about that.

Here's a fix:

1. Open Registry Editor (type `regedit` in start menu).
2. Locate `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` branch.
3. Check if `mailto` key is present and has a string value of `URL Protocol` attached. Note: keys are alphabetically sorted, so first there are the ones prefixed with a dot (file extensions), look for *mailto* farther down.
4. If `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\mailto` key is not missing in your registry, then the cause of your problem is somewhere else, try uninstalling IE10 (Programs and Fetures -> View installed updates -> locate IE10 and uninstall). **EDIT:** see comments - there's a solution even if `mailto` is present.
5. If `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\mailto` is missing as it was in my case, you have to restore it. In parent branch (`Classes`) right click, select New -> Key, name it `mailto`. In this new key create a string value (right click, New -> String value), give it name `URL Protocol` and you're done. Close regedit and see if it worked.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped. I added just string key "URL Protocol" with empty value under mailto node, and Explorer now behaves normally.

Comment: I think #4 is wrong.  I had the mailto key.  The thing that fixed it for me was adding the "URL Protocol" String with empty value. As @MichalMinich says.

Answer (score 1):

If the ***mailto:*** links that you are clicking which cause this behavior are local links that you are clicking on your desktop or in a "Windows Explorer" window, then follow the suggestion from Oliver Salzburg and check the association setting for the **`MAILTO`** protocol. On my computer (Windows 7 Home Premium x64), I found it at **`Control Panel\Default Programs\Associate a file type or protocol with a program`**.

If the ***mailto:*** links are on a webpage that you are viewing in your browser (IE or Firefox) then it could be an ***Add-on*** which is malfunctioning. Disable all add-ons in your browser and try clicking the ***mailto:*** links again.

For IE, you can start IE in ***No Add-ons*** mode which temporarily disables all add-ons.

Click **<kbd>Start</kbd>** button (orb) then in the Start/Run textbox, type **`No Add-ons`** to locate the link to start IE in ***No Add-ons*** mode. Or, from a `Command Prompt` window type: `iexplore.exe -extoff`.

Comment: This is **really** weird. In FF, the behavior is the same as described before (despite all the plugins being inactivated). But that's not even the beginning of the weirdness. In IE (no plugins installed) I got a bunch of windows on the screen (and a bunch of processes in the Task Manager) telling me that the default mail client isn't configured. Guess what I got in Crome! Perfect behavior - the new mail window in Windows Live Mail opened. WTF?!

Answer (score 1):

I found- Outlook Email was missing. As soon as I added( using MS Office 2010 DVD), problem was fixed.
And yes, after that, you can go to Default Program and pickup your preferred e-mail client instead of outlook. ( For example Lotus notes client)

Comment: I have Outlook installed. 2013 to be exact. Are you saying it's got to be 2010?!